# Passwords, sent as parameter, visible in url on login C#

Tags: asp.net, blazor

[image]

paramUsername and paramPassword are being sent to back end to create cookies for my login system,
but then the browser saves these parameters in url and it's not safe because user sees it...

i coded by this example and last comment provides a solution but i cannot understand it.
http://blazorhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4316/A-Demonstration-of-Simple-Server-side-Blazor-Cookie-Authentication.aspx

Comment: `<a>` does not have a `type=""` attribute (at least, not the way you're using it).

Comment: The article you linked to is full of bad advice (such as passing values containing secrets as querystring parameters, swallowing exceptions, etc) - I don't recommend you follow it.